# Obtner datos de promesa sin uso de la palabra then en javascript?

Tags: javascript, promesas

Tengo una duda:se que para obtener el dato de una promesa se usa la palabra Then. Pero me gustaría saber si existe otra forma,ejemplo:
El siguiente código funciona bien ,el resultado se guarda en la variable resultado y con un then saco los datos de la promesa. Pero solo puede ser así? No existe otra manera en la que uno pueda obtener los datos sin usar then?

```
const resultado=(async function api(){

const peticion=await fetch('https://api.hacienda.go.cr/fe/ae?identificacion=112720566')
json=await peticion.json()

return json
})()

resultado.then(resultado=>console.log(resultado))
```

Comment: Estás mezclando dos sintaxis: si usas Async y await no necesitas then

Comment: @PabloLozano Si lo necesito sino como saco los datos de la promesa guardada en la variable resultado???

Comment: `const resultado = await (async function... `

Comment: Eso es lo que hice. Pero si usted ejecuta ese código se dará cuenta que no hay forma de sacar los datos de la promesa sin usar el then. Lo animo a que ejecute ese código

Answer (score 2):

Tanto el uso de:

- `then`
- `catch`
- `finally`

Nos ayudan a obtener y manejar el eventual resultado de la promesa; entonces no veo modo de evitar manejar el estado de la promesa sin alguna de las funciones mencionadas.

Directamente lo que estás usando que es `async & await` lo pudieras administrar dentro de la propia función que se auto ejecuta por medio de una estructura de control `try/catch` que en conjunto con `await` van a terminar haciendo *casi lo mismo* que las promesas que tienes escritas de forma explícita.

Es decir pudiera quedar así:

```
const resultado=(async function api(){

const peticion=await fetch('https://api.hacienda.go.cr/fe/ae?identificacion=112720566')
try{
  json=await peticion.json()
    console.log(json)
}catch(error) {
  console.log(error.message)
}

})()
```

Ahora conviene aclarar que el que no se vean no quiere decir que las promesas y su manejo por medio de alguno de las funciones ya no existen, pues:

- Cuando hacemos uso de la palabra `await` indicamos que se pausará la ejecución para que se resuelva, *esto sería en el `try` como obtener el estado de `resolve`*
- en la sección de `catch` que pudiera equivaler a un `reject` donde la petición fallo y en concencuencia obtendremos el mensaje de ese estado.

Te invito a leer la documentación de Mozilla developer donde dice y cito <sup>1</sup>

> La finalidad de las funciones async/await es simplificar el comportamiento del uso síncrono de promesas y realizar algún comportamiento específico en un grupo de Promises. Del mismo modo que las Promises son semejantes a las devoluciones de llamadas estructuradas, async/await se asemejan a una combinación de generadores y promesas.

**Referencias**

- <sup>1</sup>  [Mozilla Developer](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/funcion_asincrona)

Comment: El problema es que algunas veces deseo guardar el resultado que me devuelve la promesa en el then en una variable y luego poder utilizarla posteriormente  pero eso no se puede o yo no he podido. Siempre uno tiene que realizar todo lo que quiere hacer de una vez dentro del then o sino no hay forma de sacar eso de ahí. O existe alguna forma de guardar un valor dentro de un then y utilizar ese valor posteriormente? Yo no he podido hacer eso!!